# Why doesn't this event work correctly?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

i have two hyperlink in my code that contains image when i clear second one the first work but when both of them wrote like this the btnClose work as the btnnew . it meanse the event (btnAdd_Click) work for both of them and i dont know why

```
<HyperlinkButton   x:Name="btnClose"  Click="btnClose_Click"> 
    <HyperlinkButton.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform />
    </HyperlinkButton.RenderTransform>
    <Canvas>
        <Image     Source="/ITStock;component/Images/undo.png"  Height="20" Width="20"Margin="10,5,0,0"/>
    </Canvas>
</HyperlinkButton>   
<HyperlinkButton  x:Name="btnNew" Click="btnAdd_Click" >
    <HyperlinkButton.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform   /> 
    </HyperlinkButton.RenderTransform>
    <Canvas>
        <Image  Source="/ITStock;component/Images/edit_add.png"  Height="20" Width="20"  Margin="45,5,0,0"/>
    </Canvas>
</HyperlinkButton>


private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("OpenMainPage"); 
}

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    stock = new SR_BLStock.Stock();
    if (stock != null)
    { 
        dgStock1.RowDetailsVisibilityMode = DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.Collapsed;
        Grid grUsc = new Grid();
        grUsc.Margin = new Thickness(50);
        Border b = new Border(); 
        b.Name = "uscBorder"; 
        b.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black); 
        b.Opacity = 0.6; 
        NewStock usc = new NewStock(stock); 
        dgStock1.IsEnabled = false; 
        dg.IsEnabled = false; 
        grUsc.Children.Add(usc); 
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(grUsc);
    } 
}
```

Comment: <HyperlinkButton   x:Name="btnClose"  Click="btnClose_Click" >
<HyperlinkButton.RenderTransform><TranslateTransform />
</HyperlinkButton.RenderTransform><Canvas><Image     Source="/ITStock;component/Images/undo.png"  Height="20" Width="20"  Margin="10,5,0,0"/><ToolTipService.ToolTip>
<ToolTip Content="خروج"></ToolTip></ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Canvas></HyperlinkButton>

Comment: <HyperlinkButton  x:Name="btnNew" Click="btnAdd_Click" ><HyperlinkButton.RenderTransform><TranslateTransform   /></HyperlinkButton.RenderTransform> <Canvas><Image  Source="/ITStock;component/Images/edit_add.png"  Height="20" Width="20"  Margin="45,5,0,0"/> <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
 <ToolTip Content="جديد"></ToolTip> </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
 </Canvas> </HyperlinkButton>

Comment: @shima:  Please take a few minutes to read the very simple markdown documentation, a synopsis of which is there on the right hand side when editing.  It would have saved you posting those ugly comments

Comment: Add the code of event handlers to your question.

Comment: The code as you've posted it should work fine, they both have their own click handlers. If they are both firing the same click handler, then you must be doing something wrong elsewhere. So in other words the code you've posted is insufficient to determine the problem.

Comment: thnx for your help but in code side i wrote this code:        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("OpenMainPage");
        }

Comment: private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   { stock = new SR_BLStock.Stock();
  if (stock != null)            {
 dgStock1.RowDetailsVisibilityMode = DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.Collapsed;
Grid grUsc = new Grid();
 grUsc.Margin = new Thickness(50);
  Border b = new Border();
   b.Name = "uscBorder";
   b.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
   b.Opacity = 0.6;
  NewStock usc = new NewStock(stock);
  dgStock1.IsEnabled = false;
 dg.IsEnabled = false;
   grUsc.Children.Add(usc);
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(grUsc);
   }        }